How can I create range-Doppler spectrograms from NEXRAD level3 data?
I would like to create range-Doppler spectrograms (Doppler velocity on x-axis, range on y-axis) using NEXRAD level 3 data, to create something like this (from this paper):

I have done image processing using FFTs in the past, but am new to radar signal processing (and apologize if this is not the correct forum).
My understanding is that the spectrogram shown is for a single radial/azimuth from "a scanning Doppler polarimetric X-band radar named IDRA".  The level 3 NEXRAD velocity data contains, for each radial, a linear array in which each value represents the measured doppler velocity for one range bin along that radial.  So I'm not sure how I could create a 2D power spectrum as shown in the figure, from a 1D array of data.
Thus, my questions:

is it possible to create range-Doppler spectrograms from NEXRAD level 3 data? (or has crucial information been processed out already?)
if it is possible, do I need to use reflectivity (array of reflectivity values in range x azimuth grid) or velocity (array of doppler velocity values in range x azimuth grid) files, or both, or other?

Any "how-to" or fundamentals references appreciated.
